# Make pre-commit check in subdirectory of repository?

Tags: git, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit

I'm trying to get a pre-commit check to run a command (in npm) not in the root of the git repository (I have a folder "frontend" that contains the npm installation). This sounds trivial, but so far I have found no pre-commit package that supports this directly. I came up with a workaround, where pre-commit launches a script, then the script makes a change of directory and then it runs the command, but I would like something more direct. Pre-commit packages I have tried:

- pre-commit (python-based) https://pre-commit.com/
- pre-commit (npm-based) https://github.com/observing/pre-commit
- husky (npm based) https://github.com/typicode/husky

None of these seem to support this directly

Any alternative packages to these would be welcome, or perhaps if I missed a setting in these somewhere.

A similar question was asked here for husky, but the answer again relied on a shell script: [Husky npm package Pre-Commit hook not working in sub directory repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73535750/husky-npm-package-pre-commit-hook-not-working-in-sub-directory-repository)

UPDATE: Following comments, I will revise the emphasis of this question. I would really like to find out how to do this in one the three options I specified, although other solutions are welcome.

Comment: asking for tool recommendations on SO is off topic as it tends to lead to spammy / advertisery answers

Comment: Sure - I've updated the emphasis of the question

Comment: now your question is overly broad

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found a solution to this problem with the module Husky:

By design, husky install must be run in the same directory as .git, but you can change directory during prepare script and pass a subdirectory. Assuming your subdirectory is `frontend`:

// package.json

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "prepare": "cd .. && husky install frontend/.husky"
  }
}
```

In your hooks, you'll also need to change directory:

```bash
# .husky/pre-commit
# ...
cd frontend
npm run command
```

Solution from the husky documentation: https://typicode.github.io/husky/#/?id=custom-directory

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by making a symlink to the package.json and node_modules folder in the root of repository.

`ln -s frontend/package.json package.json`

`ln -s frontend/node_modules node_modules`